# How to manually insert js code on each load of page via the console of the browser

Tags: javascript, console

I am preparing JavaScript code that shows a random number for user as follows: if the user spend more than two minutes to pass to the next web page or if the actual page has the GET parameter "&source", the random number is replaced by another one. otherwise, the same random number is displayed for all the web pages.

The problem is that the JavaScript code should be executed manually from browser console on each page load: I should prepare a code that can be integrated to any web page from console.

Is there any difference from the normal case (include script with`<script></script>`)

Comment: Each page load? So you would need to manually execute it

Comment: You will need a browser extension to do that automatically. The javascript logic sounds quite simple, I guess that is not a challenge. Have a look on this gist for more details about how to build a simple browser extension in chrome. https://gist.github.com/danharper/8364399

Comment: @SorinVladu Thanks for your help. I am supposed to write the js code and give it to the rest of the team and they will execute it manually through the browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting! In future posts, please try to provide some code or an example of something you've tried previously.

Anyways, here is a brief example of a script that will check for an existing number, check to see if there is a `&source` parameter set, begin the timer if there isn't one, and generate a new number if the timer finishes or the parameter is set.

To save the information between pages, you should consider using [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). This will allow you to check for and save the number to be used on later loads.

Note that this snippet isn't going to work until you bring it into your own page. Also, as @Sorin-Vladu mentioned, you'll have to use a browser extension if you don't have access to modify the pages you're running the script on.

```js
const timeout = 120000

// This can be replaced by your manual execution
window.onload = () => {
  start()
}

function start() {
  // Attempt to pull the code from storage
  let code = localStorage.getItem('code')
  console.log(code)
  
  // Get the URL parameters
  let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  
  // Check to see if the source parameter exists
  if (!urlParams.has('source')) {
    // If not, begin the timer
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCode()
    }, timeout)
  } else {
    setCode()
  }
}

function setCode() {
  const code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)
  localStorage.setItem('code', code)
  console.log(code)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To save the information between pages, I cannot use window.localStorage because a requirement for the exercise is to use cookies to save certain information